# How linear displacement behaves as distance that is a scalar

Tags: classical-mechanics

When a particle moves in a circle, linear displacement in one complete rotation equals to the circumference of the circle where as the displacement of the particle is actually zero as it comes back to its initial position,

how can linear displacement being a displacement gives two different values,

pl clarify this confusion,

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, *displacement* is a vector quantity defined as:
$$\Delta\vec r=\vec r_2-\vec r_1$$
On the other hand the *distance* that a particle has moved is a different concept. In the case of rectilinear motions, the displacement and distance correspond, however, if the particle moves along a curvilinear path or closed path like the circle in your example, the displacement can be zero while the distance is equal to the circumference of the given circular path. Generally, *distance* and *displacement* are not the same things.